# Slow Routing Problem

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, dmz

I've got the following network:

```
 ADSL(10.) --- Router (10.0.0.50,172.0.0.1) --- "HTTPServer (172.0.0.10)"
     |
     |
      --- "HTTPS Server" (10.0.0.3)
      --- Another computer (10.0.0.5)
```

I configured my ADSL router to forward HTTPS to 10.0.0.3  (HTTPS server) and it works perfectly fine.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing for HTTPServer (172.0.0.10) so I configured my ADSL modem to forward HTTPS to 10.0.0.50 and configured 10.0.0.50 (Router) to forward HTTP to 172.0.0.10 (HTTPServer).

This still works but insanely slow. I know that the router is fine because if I access to HTTPS port of the router from 10.0.0.5 it works fast, but when I access it over the ADSL modem it's getting **really really slow** (*it works but keeps timing out and every request takes seconds*).

I can't change my network design (that separate LAN is in there for security), why do you think this is an issue. Why there is performance problem when it goes through

```
ADSL - Router - HTTPServer
```

?

My router : Netgear Prosafe FVG318

Answer (score 2):

It could be a MTU problem. I would suggest to take a trace with tcpdump/wireshark on 172.0.0.10 and on a client computer on internet to compare them and see if fragmentation is done somewhere.
What kind of modem/router "ADSL" is ? How is he connecting to internet (PPPoE?, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The "really really slow" immediately rings a bell. Force full duplex on both ADSL and 10.0.0.50. Probably one of them auto-negotiated to half duplex (and is now ignoring incoming packets when transmitting anything, causing a wave of TCP retries).

Comment: I would have problem when performing test from 10.0.0.5, no ?

Comment: errrrrrr... true :/

Comment: I was meaning 'he' of course. Anyway it's a good point to check.